# Difference between $f(x(t))$ and $f(t,x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, notation

Why is there a difference between the two differential equations:

$\overset{.}{x}(t)=f(x(t))$ and    $\overset{.}{x}(t)=f(t,x)$ ?

Comment: i think one needs more context to answer this question.

Comment: The latter is not-quite-correct shorthand for $\dot{x}(t) = f(t,x(t))$. Do you see how that's different from the first?

Comment: The first one is *time-invariant*. It is already a huge difference.

Comment: In the first one, $f$ does not depend on $t$, in the second one it does. However, you can always turn $\dot x(t) = f(t,x(t))$ into $\dot X(t) = F(X(t))$ by $X(t) = (t, x(t))$ and $F((t, x)) = (1, f(t,x))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I see $x(t)$, I think of it as a path (or particle) moving depending on $t$ (time).

$f(x(t))$ is a function on the position of the particle only.  Therefore, even if the particle returns to the same point more than once, the value of $f(x(t))$ is the same every time.  An example of such a function is $f(x(t))=2x(t)$.

On the other hand, $f(t,x(t))$ means that $t$ is an input to the function as well.  Therefore, if $x(t_1)=x(t_2)$, then $f(t_1,x(t_1))$ might not be the same as $f(t_2,x(t_2))$ because the function can depend on $t$.  For example, you might have $f(t,x(t))=2tx(t)$.

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out in the comments, there is a difference between both expression. Here are two relevant links you can check out. But first let's state the following:

You can always transform a system of $\overset{.}{x}(t)=f(t,x(t))$ into a system of $\overset{.}{x}(t)=f(x(t))$ by going $1$ dimension higher, it is a quite basic procedure.

Your second one $\overset{.}{x}(t)=f(t,x(t))\equiv\overset{.}{x}(t)=f(t,x)$ describes a general [ordinary differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation) of order $1$.

Your first one $\overset{.}{x}(t)=f(x(t))$ is a special case of the second one, a so called [autonomous system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)) or time-invariant system.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a parameter $t$, a function $x$ which depends on $t$. In your first equation you have a function $f$ which does something to $x$, which you can then express as a function of $t$ by substituting that in (although since you don't know $x(t)$, this is a moot point). In the second equation, you have a function of two variables, $x$ and $t$, and you can do anything you want to $x$ or $t$ (within reason).

This is quite important if you want to actually solve the equation. The first is only as hard to solve as $1/f(x)$ is to integrate. The second can be *much* harder to solve in general.

Answer (score 1):

There is much difference. The first only depends on $x$ (which is parameterized by $t$), so $t$ does not appear explicitly in the equation. The second one can be time-dependent (if $t$ is interpreted as time).

In physics, the difference would be something like this:

The first equation describes a phenomenon, where the velocity of an object only depends on its position. The second equation can have arbitrary driving forces present, that change in time and space.

If there was a second derivative on the left, the difference would mean that in the first case, the energy is conserved and in the second it probably isn't (autonomous versus driven system).